Fix C++ errors in R package that only appear with clang but not gcc
Derived from Test R package with C++ code errors that appear with clang-asan but not gcc
The previous question was about the clang setup, that I am not so sure that I implemented correctly. This is about the specifics of a function that I wrote.
I got these errors testing with clang but not with gcc:
0x50600003aac0 is located 0 bytes inside of 54-byte region [0x50600003aac0,0x50600003aaf6)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x591875c9eb1d in operator new(unsigned long) (/home/pacha/github/open-redatam/rpkg/dev/R-devel/bin/exec/R+0x10bb1d) (BuildId: e68667ae741dfff9d511b6cf00e1bbc0361b9d69)
    #1 0x752b77d52ebf in std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so.1+0x4eebf) (BuildId: 78e555136344730317fc05363f9e8afdd6f83ca4)
    #2 0x752b6be31cfc in RedatamLib::ByteArrayReader::TryReadStr(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*, bool) /home/pacha/github/open-redatam/rpkg/src/redatamlib/ByteArrayReader.cpp:114:13
    #3 0x752b6be5e4e0 in RedatamLib::FuzzyEntityParser::TryGetEntity() /home/pacha/github/open-redatam/rpkg/src/redatamlib/FuzzyEntityParser.cpp:45:17
    #4 0x752b6be5d7af in RedatamLib::FuzzyEntityParser::ParseEntities() /home/pacha/github/open-redatam/rpkg/src/redatamlib/FuzzyEntityParser.cpp:19:14
    #5 0x752b6bf30f94 in RedatamLib::RedatamDatabase::OpenDictionary(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) /home/pacha/github/open-redatam/rpkg/src/redatamlib/RedatamDatabase.cpp:33:25
    #6 0x752b6bf30cda in RedatamLib::RedatamDatabase::RedatamDatabase(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) /home/pacha/github/open-redatam/rpkg/src/redatamlib/RedatamDatabase.cpp:20:3

With gcc, the package passes the R CMD check and gh-actions.
The first error is about this (https://github.com/pachadotdev/open-redatam/blob/main/rpkg/src/redatamlib/ByteArrayReader.cpp#L108-L126):
bool ByteArrayReader::TryReadStr(string* output, bool filterByContent) {
  size_t ogPos = m_currPos;

  try {
    uint16_t len = ReadInt16LE();
    if (!(0 < len && 128 > len && m_currPos + len <= m_endPos)) {
      throw std::length_error("Error: Invalid string length.");
    }

    *output = ReadString(len);
  } catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
    throw;  // Directly re-throw bad_alloc without additional wrapping
  } catch (const std::exception&) {
    SetPos(ogPos);
    return false;
  }

  return filterByContent ? IsValidStr(*output) : true;
}

It is not clear to me why this works with gcc but not with clang.
Is there anything gcc-specific that I did there? I made sure to use C++11 and use standard code for compatibility.

Same question or issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79139143/test-r-package-with-c-code-errors-that-appear-with-clang-asan-but-not-gcc ?

the previous question was about the clang setup, that I am not so sure that I implemented correctly. This is about the specifics of a function that I wrote. I edited to clarify

You cannot meaningfully compare 'standard build with gcc' and 'sanitizer-enhanced for asan, ubsan, ...'.  It is quite common for some code to pass the former (and "this does not prove correctness") yet fail the latter.  That is why the latter is running as an extra check.

I am a bit confused. In my C++ class we did everything with gcc and valgrind, therefore I have to ask now and declare my ignorance.

Valgrind is a different tool. Try the repo documentation on sanitizers for an overview.
